# Parsing number to text by OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I'm trying to save number in Excel file using OpenXML. The problem is that even when I use DataType as string, in Excel file it's still number.

```html
                SheetData.AppendChild(new Row(
                new Cell()
                {
                    CellValue = new CellValue("2156"),
                    DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String)
                }));
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the value with quotes around it or setting the cell format?

Comment: quotes doesn't satisfy me because excel file also contains them. How to set cell format ? I found in documentation that there is something like CellFormat() but how to apply it in this case ?

Comment: or maybe StyleIndex  ? But which value set as string ?

Comment: You are setting the correct DataType - if you open the file with excel you should notice that the value in the appended cell is left justified which is the default for text (numbers default to right justified) & when you select the cell you get a little warning box appear & when you place the mouse cursor over it you get the following text _"The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe."_.  If you set _"DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number)"_ - you will see the value right justified & no warning box when you select the cell.

Comment: Yeah I know , but the point is that I want to save it as text

Comment: The value is text - what are you expecting to be different?

Comment: THe value is text but in Excel it wants to convert to number. The same thing is with "9-11-99" it warns that year has only 2 digits. I want it as text not a date or number

Comment: I think you're looking for the [`IgnoredErrors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.ignorederror?view=openxml-2.8.1) class. I don't have time to write an answer right now but will try to later.

Comment: Setting a number format is not simple in OpenXML - you need to find the correct format in WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats & set the index of that as the StyleIndex. If the format does not exist then you need to create it & add it to the CellFormats. See here for a similar question, to set the Text number format you should look for numberFormatID = 49. I suggest you explore the data stored in the .xslx file - create a simple spreadsheet with the data you want in it, save it & rename as .zip - then look through all the .xml files to see exactly how the data is stored.